# AWK arguments vs file

Tags: awk

Let's say I have two pieces of code:

```
awk ' BEGIN {for (i=0; i<ARGC-1; i++) {printf "ARGV[%d] = %s\n", i, ARGV[i]}} {print "So as you can see, complications can occur."} ' one two three four
```

This piece won't work unless there's a file called `one` in the directory.

```
awk ' BEGIN {for (i=0; i<ARGC-1; i++) {printf "ARGV[%d] = %s\n", i, ARGV[i]}}' one two three four
```

This will work normally and `one two three four` will be understood as arguments. So why does the former not work? What makes awk think something is from a file and something is argument? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running any `BEGIN` blocks, if there is any remaining code, it is run once per line of the input - which means `awk` has to read its input. If there is anything in `ARGV` when `awk` goes to read input, it is interpreted as a list of files to open and read; otherwise, standard input is read instead.

In your example, the `print` line that mentions complications is not inside a `BEGIN` block, so it won't be run until `awk` reads a line of input - which it will try to do from the file `one` because that its the first argument.

If you want to pass arguments to your AWK program without having them treated as filenames, you can; just be sure not to leave them in `ARGV` if you also have any code outside `BEGIN` blocks:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
       for (i=0; i<ARGC-1; i++) {printf "ARGV[%d] = %s\n", i, ARGV[i]};
       delete ARGV} 
     {print "So as you can see, complications can occur."}' one two three four
```

The above will print out the message and then wait for a line on standard input. Upon receiving any lines, it will print out the message about complications.

If you just want an AWK program to do its thing without trying to read and process any input - leaving aside that AWK is perhaps an odd choice for that scenario - simply put all the code inside one or more `BEGIN` blocks.  If `awk` finishes the `BEGIN` blocks and finds no other code, it will exit without attempting to read any input.

Comment: Excellent answer. One point of interest, is that one can remove, say, the second argument with `delete ARGV[2]`. What is left over after processing the command line, will be used as files. An extra note is that `awk` has its own command line processor. This can be disabled by running scripts with `-E` in stead of the standard `-f`. Then you'll have full control over the options, if you happen to write am awk program that should work as a real script.

Comment: If I don't want it to wait for my `stdin` but print arrays of arguments and then print something, how do I do that? I tried using `awk ' BEGIN{...} END{print "Complications"} ' one two three four` and it waits until I `CTRL+D`.

Comment: Just put the whole program inside the `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` needs valid input data (either from file or stdin) to execute code outside `BEGIN` block. In first snippet you have a `print` statement outside `BEGIN` which will be executed if `awk` is given some valid input (even if empty). However if your input files don't exist then awk will return this error:

```
fatal: cannot open file `one' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

2nd snippet works without valid input because you only have code inside `BEGIN` block.